# What does nginx -s reopen do?

Tags: nginx

What does 'nginx -s reopen' really do? The nginx documentation says that it reopens logs. I tried it out from a terminal while nginx was running, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something happened. You just didn't see it :) Calling `nginx -s reopen`, or sending a `SIGUSR1` signal to an `nginx` process, while cause `nginx` to reopen its logs files.

This can become handy in case you (or a program like `logrotate`) alter a log file and want `nginx` to refresh its file descriptors. By doing this, `nginx` places its write cursor at the (new) end of the file, and prevents log corruptions (which would occur if `nginx` wrote an entry at a wrong/outdated file offset).

Comment: Thanks! Another question. What does it mean to rotate logs? Why do we need to do it?

Comment: Log rotation prevents log files from getting too big :) `logrotate` regularly truncates these files, and creates archives of what's been truncated. This is why your `/var/log` directory usually fills up with `.gz` files.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith so is there a slight chance of loosing some entries between rotating this way?

Comment: @JohnWHSmith is threre any resource where we can read more about this?